# apostrophe " ' " retrieved as &#39; in tornado-python template

Tags: python, html, character-encoding, escaping, tornado

I have a record in database [**Maria Db**]that contains an apostrophe ',when i retrieve the data from database the apostrophe become `&#39` which is a **HTML Character Reference**; am using Python and tornado as a framework to generate data in template
My Question is how to prevent apostrophe from becoming `&#39` ?

Note : when i retrieve the list from database and print it there is no `&#39` the conversion happens when i generate values in tornado template so the problem is not from the database.

**1 - retrieving the list**
`(nb_, results_) = await BddInterface.execute("SELECT switches ... )`

**2 - append results in a list :**

```
tmp_S_array.append(tmp_s)
tmp_S_array.append(tmp_n)
tmp_S_array.append(tmp_a)
```

**3- render the list :**

```
   self.render(template.html,items=tmp_S_array)
```

**4- In the template**

```
        <option value="" SELECTED></option>
            {% for item1 in items %}
               <optgroup label="{{ escape(item1[0]) }}">
                {% for item2 in item1[1] %}
                   <option value="{{ escape(item2) }}">{{escape(item2)}}</option>
             {% end %}
             {% end %}
```

in the logs when i log the list apostrophe is there
**Info** Information Switches =["Cote d'Azur", '##',... ]
in the option in the template
it shows like this "d&#39Azur"

Comment: How do you retrieve, process and render it?

Comment: @KlausD. i select the data from database with a normal python query , store it in a list and render it in the tornado get methode (self.render) in the template i use a for loop to show the list everything good except for a one record containing apostrophe

Comment: Add all relevant code to the question!

Comment: @KlausD. i've edited the question , i posted just the relevant things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apostrophe or single-quote character is being escaped by the `escape` function in the template.

When you're processing the value after form submission, you can unescape it the handler like this:

```py
from tornado.escaping import xhtml_unescape

class MyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        value = xhtml_unescape(submitted_value_in_the_form)

        ...
```

Comment: Thanks Man.Yeah it's escaping it by default but what worked for me really was to just remove that escape in the template i don't know how it ends up there also i didn't know what is does until i research on your xhtml_unescape trick i found out about it

Comment: @Aub Escaping the data helps you mitigate XSS vulnerabilities. If the data that you're displaying in the html template was submitted by a user, then you must escape it in the html templates. Please read about XSS attacks.

Comment: Yes i get it , fortunately in my case i just need to display data from the database in a option list, since it's french it has a lot of apostrophes.There is no form submission but thanks for the info i appreciate it